# Microsoft PWA Online custom fields

Tags: c#, project

Do not know if this is the appropriate forum but...

I have a project with references to Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client v15 and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client v15.

Code is based on sample from https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.projectserver.client.project.customfields_di_pj14mref.aspx

The code works fine when I do not include custom fields but fails with and un-handled exception when I do include custom fields.

I have checked the actual project in PWA to see if it has a value for custom field and it does. I fact this code works fine for 48 of the 376 projects on site and they are not checked-out.

I have also confirmed that I do have sufficient permission on the PWA online site

I have tried various examples but this is the closest to working.

```
    using (ProjectContext projContext = new ProjectContext("https://xxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa"))
        {
            SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in "MyPassword1".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
            projContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("myuser@mydomain.com", passWord);

            projContext.Load(projContext.Projects);
            projContext.ExecuteQuery();

            if (projContext.Projects.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(projContext.Projects.Count);
                for (int i = 0; i < projContext.Projects.Count; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var pubProj = projContext.Projects[i].IncludeCustomFields;
                        projContext.Load(pubProj);
                        projContext.Load(pubProj.CustomFields);
                        projContext.ExecuteQuery(); //Error happens hear and error not handled

                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the projects did not have all their mandatory fields filled. Cannot explain how this causes the issue